# Can low reputation users be rate limited on room creation on chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, new-users

A [user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/218421/wide) recently prompted me to join chat. When I inadvertently clicked his name in the chat window (I was aiming for the message arrow beside it) I suddenly realized that he had created a half dozen rooms for other users.

Ughh.

So upon joining the chat and asking if he had created a Q on [SO] he comes back with (what appears to be, according to google translate) a lot of Turkish. I'm still not sure I understood what he said. This is not really pertinent to the story *except* to say that he *did not* create a Q according to his most recent questions and the question he as asking in chat.

So, the point of this feature request is, he had already created a half dozen rooms, when the C# lounge would've been good enough (there's certainly people in there).

Can we rate limit low rep users on room creation on chat, or, alternately, if they create more than 3 in a 15 minute window flag a mod for investigation? One or the other.

Comment: Or perhaps limit the number of rooms that can be created to a certain number if their rep is "too low". There are lots of possible ways to do it, but it should be a rep-based limit of some kind.

Comment: That sounds reasonable too. I see a problem, I'm not quite sure what the answer is.

Comment: "Ughh." -- Yeah, that sums it up pretty well :\

Comment: As a followup to whoever is curious, he wanted something akin to a jQuery Dialog. I'm willing to bet he has 1000 other problems, as I was only asking about a potential solution, but whatever ;-)